# How do combine formulas to be used for VLOOKUP to search for a part number in a text string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of part numbers that are combined with their old part numbers
so e.g. `PN1234/XMS1234`, the XMS part number is what I need and the strings are all different lengths and in different positions.
So I need VLOOKUP to find the XMS part number and bring me the price from a different spreadsheet that has the part number correctly.

I have solved this problem now by using text to columns, but in future i think this could be solved faster. I tried combining MID and SEARCH and LEN to bring me the correct length for the part numbers but none of them were foolproof.
I also tried

```
=vlookup(J2&"*",table array,index number,0)
```

but this didn't really pick up anything.

Thank you for any help in advance.

EDIT: Additional information to clarify the problem.
So if you like at sheet 1 image, i have highlighted the list of part numbers that i am trying to have vlookup search against, sheet 2 is the table array i want vlookup to pull the retail cost.

I tried a formula along the lines of `=VLOOKUP(MID(J3,SEARCH("X",J3),?),table,13,0)` 
But i couldn't figure out how to tell the MID formula how many characters it needed to return because if the xms part number is at the start of the text string it will bring too much of the text string back if I put too high a number. is there anyway to get MID to stop at the /?

Sheet 1:
[image: Sheet 1 VLOOKUP problem]

Sheet 2:
[image: Sheet 2 VLOOKUP problem]

Comment: is the XMS part are always on the last?

Comment: No, the XMS part is usually the front but it varies down the list.

Comment: add some more examples to the question with XMS is various other places. Also add images of your data with lookup table , desired output etc

Comment: I have amended the original post with images and the formula i attempted to use to fix the issue, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,3)="XMS",LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("XMS",A1)+1))
```

If the string starts with XMS then get the characters from the start up to the /
If the string doesn't start with XMS then get the characters after the /

So `PN1234/XMS1234` produces `XMS1234`
And `XMS1234/PN1234` produces `XMS1234`

Are there any other formats for your data?

Comment: This works fantastically, except for if the XMS data is stand alone.
Do you think it would work if i added '=IF(A1="*/"),A1,Code you stated above here)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This now works due to the answer given above with also combining it with formula ISNUMBER and SEARCH.
e.g. `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",J2)),IF(J2="*/",J2,IF(LEFT(J2,3)="XMS",LEFT(J2,SEARCH("/",J2)-1),RIGHT(J2,LEN(J2)-SEARCH("XMS",J2)+1))),J2)`

Thank you to all who helped.